# LWJGL Rotating Only One Object On Screen

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I'm trying to rotate one of two objects on the screen. How should I do this? I can only get it to rotate all the objects on the screen.
Code:

```
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(0f, .5f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(.5f, .5f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(.5f, 0f, 0f);
        glEnd();
        glRotated(.1, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        glRotated(.1, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        glRotated(.1, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3f(2f, 0f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(2f, .5f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(2.5f, .5f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(2.5f, 0f, 0f);
        glEnd();
```

code I have so far.

Comment: You see both quads? And both are rotated? Currently you only rotate by a very small amount (one tenth of a degree) which will hardly be noticeable.

Comment: I called glIdentity() before the game loop so it rotates .1 degrees every frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `glRotated` endlessly without resetting the matrices is a bad idea. Rounding errors will accumulate. You currently don't call `glIdentity` each frame. Render each frame the following way:

1. Call `glIdentity`
2. Draw the first quad
3. Rotate
4. Draw the second quad

The way you render things the rotation difference of the two quads is only 1/10th of a degree on the three axis - which is not noticeable.

Be sure to read up on OpenGL, to learn the current way of OpenGL programming and try to improve your code. It looks as if you don't quite understand what you're doing, no offence.

Answer (score 1):

use glPushMatrix(); before your rotation transforms and glPopMatrix(); after the second quad is rendered then only the second quad will be affected by the rotation transforms.